# Get all data since creation until today from ad account using facebook ads api for python

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

Is it possible to get lifetime data from using facebookads api on python? I tried to use `date_preset:lifetime` and `time_increment:1`, but got a server error instead. And, then I found this on their website:

"We use data-per-call limits to prevent a query from retrieving too much data beyond what the system can handle. There are 2 types of data limits:

By number of rows in response, and
By number of data points required to compute the total, such as summary row."

Any way I can do this? And, another question, is there like any way to pull raw data from facebook ad account, like a dump of all the data that resides on facebook for an ad account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing is to try is to add the `limit` parameter, which limits the number of results returned per page.

However, if the account has a large amount of history, the likelihood is that the total amount of data is too great, and in this case, you'll have to query ranges of data.

As you're looking for data by individual day, I'd start trying to query for month blocks, and if this is still too much data, query for each date individually.